# How to reload one livewire component from another component?

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-livewire

I have components named TopicSolution, AddToCart, and CartCounter. I want to update the CartCounter value after clicking Add To cart button but cart counter is not updating.

1. I have a livewire component named topic-solutions which is inside the livewire folder and that component has another component named add-to-cart which is inside the livewire > cart folder (note: it have parent div)

   [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXmSm.jpg)
2. views of the add-to-cart component have this code

   ```
   <button wire:click="addToCart" class="btn mt-3 ml-1">Add To Cart</button>
   ```
3. when add to cart button is clicked it emits updateCartCounter which is another component inside livewire>cart

   ```
   $this->emit('updateCartCounter');
   ```
4. And CartCounter has listeners named updateCartCounter

   ```
   protected $listeners = [
       'updateCartCounter' => 'render'
   ];
   ```

I tried the following code as well

```
protected $listeners = [
    'updateCartCounter' => '$refresh'
];
```

But did not work. that CartCounter component is not refreshing/reloading.

Comment: If you want to refresh a component, use the magic method `'cartCounterUpdate' => '$refresh',`

Comment: @Qirel I tried that one as well did not work. I created these components within a subfolder maybe that's why there is a problem. Is it the right way to emit listeners as shown in the question for the subfolder??

Comment: Doesn't matter if its in a subfolder or not. Are both components loaded on the same page?

Comment: @Qirel yeah I used two components in same page and I also used the component inside a component.

Comment: @Qirel have a look I updated a question

Answer (score 0):

As @[Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) suggested to you, you can use the magic method '$refresh' directly in the listener. Test it developing the method like this

```
protected $listeners = [
    'cartCounterUpdate'
];

public function cartCounterUpdate()
{
   dd('the event was emited');
}
```

Comment: yeah I did the same thing for testing as you say and it works but cartcounter component did not refresh.

Comment: well then you should share the code you're writing and explain to us what you expect from it

Comment: have a look please I updated a question